# Displaying a div based on select element value with JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to display a div and hide other div when the select element hold the corresponding value.

I created a select element with 4 options, the default with empty value plus three others, lower, upper, higher. I placed three hidden div elements below containing the content for each of the 3 options: lower, upper and higher. I wanted to show and hide each div based on the values of the select element. Here is my code:

```js
const departments = document.querySelector("#departments");
const lowerdep = document.querySelector(".lower-dep");
const upperdep = document.querySelector(".upper-dep");
const higherdep = document.querySelector(".higher-dep");

if (departments.value = "") {
  lowerdep.style.display = "none";
  upperdep.style.display = "none";
  higherdep.style.display = "none";

} else if (departments.value = "lower") {
  lowerdep.style.display = "block";

} else if (departments.value = "upper") {
  upperdep.style.display = "block";

} else {
  higherdep.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.lower-dep,
.upper-dep,
.higher-dep {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <label class="">Department
                <select id="departments" name="departments">
                  <option value="" selected>Select Department...</option>
                  <option value="lower">Lower</option>
                  <option value="upper">Upper</option>
                  <option value="higher">Higher</option>
                </select>
              </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lower-dep">
  <div class="input-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="color1" name="color1" value="Red">
    <label for="color1"> Red</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="upper-dep">
  <div class="input-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="color1" name="color1" value="Red">
    <label for="color1"> Red</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="higher-dep">
  <div class="input-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="color1" name="color1" value="Red">
    <label for="color1"> Red</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question/problem? Are you getting any errors? Does anything happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to wrap that in an event listener, and hide all of the elements before showing:

```js
departments.addEventListener("change", function() {
    lowerdep.style.display = "none";
    upperdep.style.display = "none";
    higherdep.style.display = "none";
    
    if (departments.value == "lower") {
      lowerdep.style.display = "block";
    } else if (departments.value == "upper") {
      upperdep.style.display = "block";
    } else if (departments.value == "higher") {
      higherdep.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

This way whenever the user picks an option the corresponding `div` will be shown, and the rest will be hidden.

Also, you will want to replace each `=` with `==` in the if statements, as `=` in javascript is assignment, so the if statement will run if the value you assign is truthy. You were probably looking for `==`, the equality comparison operator instead.

Full snippet:

```js
const departments = document.querySelector("#departments");
const lowerdep = document.querySelector(".lower-dep");
const upperdep = document.querySelector(".upper-dep");
const higherdep = document.querySelector(".higher-dep");
departments.addEventListener("change", function() {
    lowerdep.style.display = "none";
    upperdep.style.display = "none";
    higherdep.style.display = "none";
    
    if (departments.value == "lower") {
      lowerdep.style.display = "block";
    } else if (departments.value == "upper") {
      upperdep.style.display = "block";
    } else if (departments.value == "higher") {
      higherdep.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

```css
.lower-dep,
.upper-dep,
.higher-dep {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <label class="">Department
                <select id="departments" name="departments">
                  <option value="" selected>Select Department...</option>
                  <option value="lower">Lower</option>
                  <option value="upper">Upper</option>
                  <option value="higher">Higher</option>
                </select>
              </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lower-dep">
  <div class="input-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="color1" name="color1" value="Red">
    <label for="color1"> Lower dep: Red</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="upper-dep">
  <div class="input-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="color1" name="color1" value="Red">
    <label for="color1"> Upper dep: Red</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="higher-dep">
  <div class="input-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="color1" name="color1" value="Red">
    <label for="color1"> Higher dep: Red</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ids are unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same id so I changed that.
2. Also added an `eventListener` to hide and show elements based on selection and just remove or add the `d-none` class as needed.
3. Your `if/else` statements were also wrong `=` is for assignment and `==` for comparisons. You can also use `switch case` like in my example.

```js
const departments = document.querySelector("#departments");
const lowerdep = document.querySelector(".lower-dep");
const upperdep = document.querySelector(".upper-dep");
const higherdep = document.querySelector(".higher-dep");

departments.addEventListener("change", function(){
  lowerdep.classList.add("d-none");
  upperdep.classList.add("d-none");
  higherdep.classList.add("d-none");
  switch (departments.value) {
    case 'lower':
        lowerdep.classList.remove("d-none");
    break;
    case 'upper':
        upperdep.classList.remove("d-none");
    break;
    case 'higher':
        higherdep.classList.remove("d-none");
    break;
  }
})
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
    <div class="">
      <label class="">Department
        <select id="departments" name="departments">
          <option value="" selected>Select Department...</option>
          <option value="lower">Lower</option>
          <option value="upper">Upper</option>
          <option value="higher">Higher</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="lower-dep d-none">
    <div class="input-check">
      <input type="checkbox" id="color-lower" name="color" value="Red">
      <label for="color-lower"> Red lower</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="upper-dep d-none">
    <div class="input-check">
      <input type="checkbox" id="color-upper" name="color" value="Red">
      <label for="color-upper"> Red upper</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="higher-dep d-none">
    <div class="input-check">
      <input type="checkbox" id="color-higher" name="color1" value="Red">
      <label for="color-higher"> Red higher</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```